# How to stop chrome from reading text selected?

Tags: google-chrome, text-to-speech

Chrome reads aloud the text selected by accident, the sudden voice frightening me. Can we turn off this feature? Badly needed on Both mobile and desktop platform.

Comment: https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/9032490?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

https://www.google.com/preferences

Please change "Spoken Answers"

[image]